# I want to set a background image to my button. I got a crash

Tags: image, button, c++-cli

I want to set a background image to my button. My background image didn't appeared on button. So I decide to log myButton.

```
this->myButton->BackgroundImage->FromFile( "c:\\red\\Desert.jpg");
myLog(this->myButton->BackgroundImage->ToString());
```

I got a crash when I logged string:

```
message Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you need to do this at run-time; have you tried setting it prior to run-time through the properties window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BackgroundImage property is a pointer to a Image object and initialy it is nullptr, so you are trying to access to methods from non-existing object. The right code could be something like that:

```
this->myButton->BackgroundImage = Image::FromFile("c:\\red\\Desert.jpg");
// Now the image object is initialized and you can log it
myLog(this->myButton->BackgroundImage->ToString());
```